# behaviour of `observe` in an `observeEvent` or `if`

Tags: r, shiny

How does an `observe` behave in `if` statement or in an `observeEvent`?
Is it autonomous from `if` or `observeEvent`?
In the following code `observe` does not activate by the `dummy` button unless the `go` button triggers the satisfied `if` condition, and then the `dummy` button always triggers `observe`.

```r
shiny::reactiveConsole(T)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "select1",
    label = "select1" ,
    choices = c("True" = T, "False" = F) ,
    selected =  "T",
    multiple = F
  ),
  
  selectInput(
    inputId = "select2",
    label = "select2" ,
    choices = c("True" = T, "False" = F) ,
    selected =  "T",
    multiple = F
  ),
  selectInput(
    inputId = "select3",
    label = "select" ,
    choices = c("True" = T, "False" = F) ,
    selected =  "T",
    multiple = F
  ),
  actionButton(inputId = "go" ,
               label = "Go"),
  actionButton(inputId = "dummy" ,
               label = "dummy")
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(eventExpr = input$go ,
               handlerExpr = {
                 inputs = reactiveValuesToList(input)
                 select_input = inputs[startsWith(names(inputs), "select") &
                                         grepl(".*[0-9]$",
                                               names(inputs))]
                 if (sum((select_input == "TRUE")) >= 2) {
                   observe({
                     input$dummy
                     print(select_input)
                   })
                 } else{
                   print("nothing")
                 }
               })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: The `if` statement is a red herring here, the problem is that you cannot nest reactive block, as in `observeEvent(..., { observe(...); })`.

Comment: Based on this code, replace your inner `observe(...)` with just `print(select_input)` (no `observe`), perhaps that will give the results you want. (I do not know what you need to happen with `observe({input$dummy})`, it is a complete no-op.)